# Comments in EXPDB parameter file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export, datapump, comments

Is there a way to put comments in a data pump export parameter file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, by using `#` at the start of a line.

Actually everything *after* the `#` sign will be ignored, so this can be used after a parameter as well.

This is a bit hidden in the manual:

> *Table names specified on the command line cannot include a pound sign (#), unless the table name is enclosed in quotation marks. Similarly, in the parameter file, if a table name includes a pound sign (#), then the Export utility interprets the rest of the line as a comment, unless the table name is enclosed in quotation marks*

Quoted from:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#sthref137